# The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/test.html' is not allowed

Tags: asp.net, html

Below is my code:

```
<form id="productForm" method="post" action="test.html">

</form>
```

Comment: What server side scripting language is used?

Comment: i mean, is it PHP or ASP.NET or Ruby?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you using any URL rewriting? (http://forums.asp.net/t/953470.aspx)

In the webserver, is POST allowed for HTML files? Try changing the extension to .ASPX or .PHP

Answer (score 3):

I found this post while working on my first Facebook app, so this may or may not be related to your underlying issue...but I was getting this same error.

While a Canvas URL value has to end in "/", the Tabl URL can be a fully qualified page (e.g. http://[DOMAIN/DIRECTORY-PATH]/Default.aspx).

I'm working locally, so **http://localhost:4604/Main/Default.aspx** worked for me.

HttpGet, HttpPost protocols do not appear to be required in the web.config (although this fix still worked with them in there).

Comment: This is exactly what was happening to me and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first that comes to mind is permissions.

What version of IIS ? By default IIS6 [prevents](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/forumarchives/inetserveriis/Aug2005/post23592869.asp) a post to a HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the  directive is used in your (supposedly) Apache web server?
You would need to check the httpd.conf for this directive and make sure that POST is allowed to be called on your file.

Nevertheless does it seem a little odd to POST on a static html file or is mod_rewrite being used to confuse people?

Answer (score 0):

The default for this error is that the POST verb is turned off at the configuration for the server. Is this happening in Cassini or in IIS? In IIS this behavior can be controlled. Also you may want to make sure that the proper handlers are in your web.config if you are still having issues after looking at the IIS configuration (if this ends up being web service related):

```
<system.web>  
    <webServices>    
        <protocols>    
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
```