# 405 (POST not allowed) HttpException when trying to apply HttpResponse.Filter

Tags: .net-4.0, iis-7.5, httpresponse, windows-server-2008-r2, responsestream

We are getting a 405 error and the following exception from IIS7 when attempting to apply a [ResponseStreamFilter](https://github.com/mindrevolution/ImageResizer-ResponsivePresets/blob/master/plugin/FilterModule/ResponseFilterStream.cs) to [HttpResponse.Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.filter.aspx):

```
HttpException: 
The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/app/Thing.asmx/Command' is not allowed.
```

We are applying the filter by using an HttpModule with code like this:

```
var rfs = new ResponseFilterStream(HttpContext.Current.Response.Filter);
rfs.TransformStream +=
    new Func<System.IO.MemoryStream, System.IO.MemoryStream>(ProcessStream);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Filter = rfs;
Log("Response stream filter applied correctly.");
```

All of the code in our HttpModule works just fine... it's all wrapped in a try-catch just to be safe and isn't throwing any exceptions, and diagnostic logging like the last line above is working correctly.

But it looks like our `ProcessStream` method in the above code is never being called.  If we apply the filter to `HttpResponse.Filter` at all, *IIS throws the 405 exception before our filter begins processing*.

**Our code has worked before on several similar systems, so we suspect IIS/machine configuration on this specific server is responsible.**  What could be causing this?

The most commonly reported cause for a 405 error in a situation like this seems to be using Url.Rewrite. ([The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/test.html' is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209324/the-http-verb-post-used-to-access-path-test-html-is-not-allowed)) However, we are never using a Url.Rewrite.

Another commonly reported cause is trailing slashes in the request URL. ([HTTP 405 on Error on HTTP POST IIS ASP .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617210/http-405-on-error-on-http-post-iis-asp-net)) But as mentioned above, the URL being requested does not end with a slash.

The app pool *is* running .NET 4.0 in a Classic pipeline ([jQuery AJAX post receives 405 error (HTTP verb POST not allowed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254123/jquery-ajax-post-receives-405-error-http-verb-post-not-allowed)), but our code has run without issue on many other systems under a Classic app pool, so there would still have to be something unique to this server's configuration. Changing to Integrated pipeline breaks the application our code is filtering, so that's not a possible workaround anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, it was a very obscure IIS bug:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368

The ExtensionlessUrl handler (`*.`) was incorrectly getting involved with the request instead of just the WebServiceHandlerFactory (`*.asmx`) as expected.  The workaround was:

1. Manually deleting the ExtensionlessUrl handler entries from the web application's handler mappings
2. Manually moving the ExtensionlessUrl handler entries under anything you actually expect to be hit
3. Adding a web.config entry under system.webServer/handlers to remove the ExtensionslessUrl handler as needed (we went with this option to make sure it got included with app demployment)

We had to burn a Microsoft support ticket on this one, since there's no way we would have figured this out in any reasonable timeframe.  Hopefully this helps someone else.